# Amazon Linux 2 / Red Hat Linux Enterprise : binutils won't install 'ld' bin

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ld, binutils, amazon-linux-2

Trying to install the mongodb extension on Amazon linux 2 (which is based on Red Hat Linux Enterprise) but I'm missing the ld extension.

I have the binutils installed, but no ld bin :(

```
binutils-2.29.1-30.amzn2.x86_64.rpm                                                 | 5.8 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installation : binutils-2.29.1-30.amzn2.x86_64                                                       1/1
/var/lib/alternatives/ld est vide !
/var/lib/alternatives/ld est vide !
  Vérification : binutils-2.29.1-30.amzn2.x86_64                                                       1/1

Installé :
  binutils.x86_64 0:2.29.1-30.amzn2

Terminé !
```

> which ld /usr/bin/which: no ld in
>   (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: all good, I have to remove an old 'ld' file in '/var/lib/alternatives/' and then reinstall binutils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all good, I have to remove an old 'ld' file in '/var/lib/alternatives/' and then reinstall binutils